Prevent node text and lines from overlapping inside node's box
It is not easy to find a suitable title for my problem, so I am open on suggestions for improvement.
In some of my TikZ drawings, I have noticed that it would be better to indicate a "two-part division" of areas in addition to the actual text.
I started accordingly and came to this result. I haven't found anything on VisualTikz that would help me directly.
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\if\ifxetex T\else\ifluatex T\else F\fi\fi T% 
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}

\colorlet{XColor}{purple}

% complete document in Sans Serif
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      fill opacity=0.2,
      text opacity=1,
      M/.style 2 args={
          draw,
          thick,
          rectangle,
          minimum height=#2em,
          minimum width=#1em,
          inner sep=0,
          outer sep=0,
          anchor=south west,      % origin for coordinates
          font={\large},
          align=center            % also req. for line break
      },
    ]
    \node[M={8}{3},fill=yellow!30] at (0,0)      (M0) {Base};
    \node[M={8}{5},above=0 of M0,fill=XColor   ] (M1) {Extension}; % upper & lower
    \draw[thick,dashed] (M1.west) -- node[midway,above] {} (M1.east);
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Unfortunately, the text font is cut through by the dash line. How do I solve the problem that the dash line stops just before the \node text and starts again just after it, without disfiguring the background color/fill? It should also work for longer text with line breaks.
My idea would be to try the TikZ 'backgrounds' library and 'scope' with \begin{scope}[on background layer] ..., I would come to 3 layers and have discarded it because it is too complicated (anyway, I didn't try this) - it is certainly easier, but how?

Set your text as a label. You can name this label and draw the line corresponding to the label.

\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}

\colorlet{XColor}{purple}

% complete document in Sans Serif
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      fill opacity=0.2,
      text opacity=1,
      M/.style 2 args={
          draw,
          thick,
          rectangle,
          minimum height=#2em,
          minimum width=#1em,
          inner sep=0,
          outer sep=0,
          anchor=south west,      % origin for coordinates
          font={\large},
          align=center            % also req. for line break
      },
    ]

\node[M={8}{3},fill=yellow!30] (M0)  at (0,0)     {Base};


\node[M={8}{5},above=0 of M0,fill=XColor,
label={[align=center, anchor=center, 
name=InnerText, 
inner sep=0pt, 
draw=red, font=\footnotesize, % optional
]center:{Extension \\ and longer text \\ with linebreaks}},
] (M1) {}; 


\draw[thick, dashed] (M1.west) -- (InnerText.west);  
\draw[thick, dashed] (M1.east) -- (InnerText.east);  

%\draw[thick, dashed] (M1.west) -- node[midway,above] {} (M1.east);  % old
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Many thanks for the solution, I would never have thought of the solution with the label.

Maybe you didn't see the multi part shapes part in the manual, or maybe it's not what you're looking for, it would be good if you indicated what result you want to obtain, but well, taking advantage of the fact that I already had an advanced code for a question that unfortunately the user deleted before I could answer it, which was about making tables with a complex style, there are also some options to work with schemes like that, I also added the multipart shapes in green.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds,positioning,fit,calc,shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{Oswald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\definecolor{BGcolor1}{HTML}{D5D0CC}
\definecolor{BGcolor2}{HTML}{898987}
\definecolor{BGcolor3}{HTML}{7B939F}
\definecolor{color0}{HTML}{02315D}
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{84B0D3}
\definecolor{color2}{HTML}{9BA87C}
\definecolor{color3}{HTML}{B9B47A}
\definecolor{color4}{HTML}{C4BA63}
\definecolor{color5}{HTML}{8C9F81}
\definecolor{color6}{HTML}{C68565}
\definecolor{color7}{HTML}{CC8F58}
\definecolor{color8}{HTML}{B492A0}
\definecolor{color9}{HTML}{D0A0AE}
\definecolor{color10}{HTML}{9589A7}
\definecolor{color11}{HTML}{BC6E80}
\definecolor{color12}{HTML}{BC5071}
\definecolor{color13}{HTML}{8194B2}
\definecolor{color14}{HTML}{E5BE49}
\definecolor{color15}{HTML}{80769B}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        x=1em,
        y=1em,
        >={Stealth[inset=0pt,length=0.5em]},
        font=\sf\tiny,
        line width=0.1pt,
        fill opacity=1,
        text opacity=1,
        P/.style 2 args={
        %   draw,
            thick,
            rectangle,
            minimum height=#2em,
            minimum width=#1em,
            inner sep=0,
            outer sep=0,
            anchor=south west,
            font=\sf,
            align=center
        },
        background rectangle/.style={%By background library
            rectangle,
            shade,
            top color=BGcolor1,
            bottom color=BGcolor2,
            shading angle=85
        },show background rectangle% To show the rackground.
        ]
        \pgfdeclarelayer{layer2}
        \pgfsetlayers{background,layer2,main}
        %Start drawing the thing...
        % Help lines to plan where put all:
%       \def\wcanvas{30}
%       \def\hcanvas{25}
%       \draw[gray!70!black,step=1em] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (\wcanvas,\hcanvas);
%       \foreach \x in {0, ..., \wcanvas} {%
%           \draw(\x,-0.9) node {\x};
%       }
%       \foreach \y in {0, ..., \hcanvas} {%
%           \node at (-0.9,\y*1) {\y};
%       }
        %Nodes See https://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf#section.7
        %and https://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf#section.17
        %First Column C1
        \draw(0,0) node[P={10}{4},text=white,fill=color0,rounded corners](C1-F1){ANNES \\[0.5em] ETABLISSEMENTS}; %Absolute coodinate
        \draw[white,line width=0.1em, dotted](C1-F1.180) -- (C1-F1.0);
        \foreach \order [count=\c from 2] in {1,...,9}{
            \ifnum\order=1
                \node[P={10}{3},fill=color\order,below=0.25em of C1-F\order,align=left,font=\sf\scriptsize](C1-F\c){};
            \else
                \node[P={10}{2},fill=color\order,below=0.25em of C1-F\order,align=left,font=\sf\scriptsize](C1-F\c){};
            \fi
        }
        \foreach \EmpName/\Subtext [count=\c from 2]in {
            ENA/{(rabat, Marrakech, Agadir,\\ Fés, Tétouan, Oujda)},
            ENAM/(MEKNES),
            ISCAE/(CASABLANCA),
            ENSK/ (Kénitra),
            ENCG/{(Marrakech, Agadir, Settat, Tanger,\\ Oujda, Eljadida, Casablanca, Kenitra,...)},
            ENSA/{(Marrakech, Agadir, Tetouan, Tanger,\\ Oujda, Eljadida, Kenitra,...)},
            ENSAM/{(Marrakech, Settat, Beni mellal,\\ Mohammedia, Tanger, Fès,...)},
            FST/{(Marrakech, Settat, Beni mellal,\\ Mohammedia, Tanger, Fès,...)},
            EST/{(Safi, Essaouira, Agadir, Elkelaa,\\ Beni mellal, Casablanca, Kenitra,...)}%
        }{
            \draw($(C1-F\c.north west)+(0.2,-0.1)$) node[font=\sf\normalsize,anchor=north west](temp){\EmpName};
            \draw($(C1-F\c.center)+(1.25,-0.25)$) node[font=\sf\tiny,align=center]{\Subtext};
        }
        %Some things in layer 2
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{layer2}
            \node[fit=(C1-F1)(C1-F10),inner sep=0](C1){};
            \draw[fill=BGcolor3]($(C1.north west)+(0.25,-0.25)$) rectangle ($(C1.south east)+(0.25,-0.25)$);
            \draw[fill=white,draw=black](C1.north west) rectangle (C1.south east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        %the rest normal nodes
            \node[P={10}{2},fill=color10,below=0.28em of C1,align=center,font=\sf\tiny](C1-F11){\scriptsize FMP-FMD-PH \\ (Selon la Répartition Géographique)};
            \node[P={10}{1},fill=color11,below=0 of C1-F11,align=center,font=\sf\tiny](C1-F12){{\scriptsize UM6P BENGUERIR} Med-Pharmacie Anglo};
            \node[P={10}{1},fill=color12,below=0 of C1-F12,align=center,font=\sf\scriptsize](C1-F13){UM6SS CASABLANCA};
            \node[P={10}{1},fill=color13,below=0 of C1-F13,align=center,font=\sf\scriptsize](C1-F14){UIASS RABAT};
            \node[P={10}{1},fill=color14,below=0 of C1-F14,align=center,font=\sf\scriptsize](C1-F15){UMP MARRAKECH};
            \node[P={10}{1},fill=color15,below=0 of C1-F15,align=center,font=\sf\scriptsize](C1-F16){UIR RABAT};
            \node[P={10}{1},fill=color5,below=0 of C1-F16,align=center,font=\sf\scriptsize](C1-F17){UPSSA AGADIR};

        %Second Column C2
        \node[P={10}{2},align=left,text=white,fill=color0, right=1em of C1-F1.north east, anchor=north west,font=\bf\rm](C2-F1){\qquad \qquad \qquad 2023};
        \node[P={1.5}{2},right=0.5em of C2-F1.south west, anchor=north west,fill=color0!70!cyan,font=\sf\scriptsize](2023-E1){SVT};
        \foreach \nodeNumber/\nodeContent/\kolor [count=\c from 1]in {
            2/PC/color1,
            3/SMA/color7,
            4/SMB/color2,
            5/ECO/color6,
            6/SGC/color3}{
            \node[P={1.5}{2},right=0 of 2023-E\c, anchor=west,fill=\kolor,font=\sf\scriptsize](2023-E\nodeNumber){\nodeContent};
        }
        \foreach \order [count=\c from 2] in {1,...,9}{
            \ifnum\order=1
            \node[P={10}{3},fill=color\order,below=2.25em of C2-F\order,align=left,font=\sf\scriptsize](C2-F\c){};
            \else
            \node[P={10}{2},fill=color\order,below=0.25em of C2-F\order,align=left,font=\sf\scriptsize](C2-F\c){};
            \fi
        }
        %Some things in layer 2
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{layer2}
            \node[fit=(C2-F1)(C2-F10),inner sep=0](C2){};
            \draw[fill=BGcolor3]($(C2.north west)+(0.25,-0.25)$) rectangle ($(C2.south east)+(0.25,-0.25)$);
            \draw[fill=white,draw=black](C2.north west) rectangle (C2.south east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        
        %Second Column C3
        \node[P={10}{2},align=left,text=white,fill=color0, right=1em of C2-F1.north east, anchor=north west,font=\bf\rm](C3-F1){\qquad \qquad \qquad 2022};
        \node[P={1.5}{2},right=0.5em of C3-F1.south west, anchor=north west,fill=color0!70!cyan,font=\sf\scriptsize](2022-E1){SVT};
        \foreach \nodeNumber/\nodeContent/\kolor [count=\c from 1]in {
            2/PC/color1,
            3/SMA/color7,
            4/SMB/color2,
            5/ECO/color6,
            6/SGC/color3}{
            \node[P={1.5}{2},right=0 of 2022-E\c, anchor=west,fill=\kolor,font=\sf\scriptsize](2022-E\nodeNumber){\nodeContent};
        }
        \foreach \order [count=\c from 2] in {1,...,9}{
            \ifnum\order=1
            \node[P={10}{3},fill=color\order,below=2.25em of C3-F\order,align=left,font=\sf\scriptsize](C3-F\c){};
            \else
            \node[P={10}{2},fill=color\order,below=0.25em of C3-F\order,align=left,font=\sf\scriptsize](C3-F\c){};
            \fi
        }
        %Some things in layer 2
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{layer2}
            \node[fit=(C3-F1)(C3-F10),inner sep=0](C3){};
            \draw[fill=BGcolor3]($(C3.north west)+(0,-0.25)$) rectangle ($(C3.south east)+(0.5,-0.25)$);
            \draw[fill=white,draw=black]($(C3.north west)+(-0.25,0)$) rectangle ($(C3.south east)+(0.25,0)$);
        \end{pgfonlayer}


        %Then draw some text based in nodenames and anchors
        \foreach \RegText/\PositoningReference/\NodeAnchor/\TextXscale in {
            {(Rabat:14.36) (Agadir:14.22)\\ (Tétouan:14.45) (Fés:15.03)\\ (Oujda:13.95) (Marrakech:14.8)}/C2-F2.center/center/1,
            {(Rabat:14.36) (Agadir:14.22)\\ (Tétouan:14.45) (Fés:15.03)\\ (Oujda:13.95) (Marrakech:14.8)}/C3-F2.center/center/1,
            14.80/C2-F3 -| 2023-E1/center/0.75,
            14.80/C2-F3 -| 2023-E2/center/0.75,
            14.80/C2-F3 -| 2023-E3/center/0.75,
            14.82/C2-F3 -| 2023-E4/center/0.75% This percent symbol is necessary to make this arrangement of code
        }{
            \draw(\PositoningReference) node[align=center,anchor=\NodeAnchor,font=\sf\scriptsize,xscale=\TextXscale]{\RegText};
        }
        %Drawing the dash lines
        \foreach \RefStart/\RefEnd in {
            C2-F3.90 -| 2023-E1.0/C2-F3.-90 -| 2023-E1.0,
            C2-F3.90 -| 2023-E2.0/C2-F3.-90 -| 2023-E2.0%
        }{
            \draw[dashed, thick](\RefStart)--(\RefEnd);
        }
        %Code for the current answer:
        %using shapes multipart https://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf#subsection.17.7
        \node[
            P={10}{2},
            fill=cyan!50!lime,
            below=0.28em of C2,
            rectangle split,
            rectangle split parts=4,
            rectangle split part align={center,left,right,left},
            draw,
            font=\sf\scriptsize,
            inner sep=0.2em
        ]{
            \normalsize Node multipart
            \nodepart{second} Second part text: With some \\ text jump.
            \nodepart{three}  text 3a \\ text 3b
            \nodepart{four}  text 4a \\ text 4b
        };
        %using brute force
        \node[
        P={10}{2},
        fill=blue!50!lime,
        below=0.28em of C3,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=4,
        rectangle split part align={center,left,right,left},
        draw,
        dashed,
        font=\sf\scriptsize,
        inner sep=0.2em
        ](NMP){
            \normalsize Node multipart
            \nodepart{second} Second part text: With some \\ text jump.
            \nodepart{three}  text 3a \\ text 3b
            \nodepart{four}  text 4a \\ text 4b
        };
        \draw[thick](NMP.north west) rectangle (NMP.south east); % bruet force xD
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}


But I thought he wanted the dashed line to be broken before and after a text and not as a dividing line between two contents. For the latter, 'mulit part' wouldn't be a bad choice.

Thank you for your solution - the table is very impressive. In fact, I saw the shapes.multipart too, but discarded it. It is imo excellent for splitting the node boxes horizontally/vertically (I have future use for it), but actually my real problem here was running the dash line into my node text. This has been solved very well by cis. I have only expanded the content of the question, clarified it.

@olStckEx, Yes, I think I intentionally didn't want to understand just to try to publish that code that was going to stay in my files without being useful to anyone.
